# Moving the numbering from the left to the right of a section adds large horizontal space in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I am trying to write solutions to exercises in a textbook. I am using subsubsections to serve as exercise headings like `\subsubsection{Exercise}`, where the natural subsubsection numbering is the exercise number. I have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}
    {#1\addcontentsline{moc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection}#1}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}
    {#1}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}
    {#1\addcontentsline{moc}{subsection}{\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}
    {#1~\thesubsubsection%
        \addcontentsline{moc}{subsubsection}{#1~\numberline{\thesubsubsection}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname%
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}
            {\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{moc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \section{Section Name}
    \subsection{Subsection Name}
    \subsubsection{Exercise}
\end{document}
```

There is a horizontal space between the subsubsection (exercise) numbering in the table of contents and the beginning of the lower dots. Any idea how to fix this spacing so that it is like the spacing for the subsection?

The long-term goal of this setup is actually to create my own `\begin{exercise}<solution here>\end{exercise}` that will behave as if I had done the above. I planned to tackle that later, but I wanted to include that idea here in case its solution may connect to this intermediate issue.

Comment: Why do use `\addcontentsline{toc}`  for numbered sections, as this is automatic?

Comment: @Bernard I create a new table of contents ```moc``` because using ```toc``` in the manner above creates two entries for each exercise in ```toc```, one with ```\thesubsubsection``` on the left of ```Exercise``` (not desired) and one on the right (desired).

Comment: I use the solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83593/115995.